# How do I apply a style to a <span> if a condition exists, and take it away if it doesn't in Rails 3?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3

The span tag currently looks like this:

```
<span class='best_in_place<%= ' list-downvoted' if upload.downvoted? %><%= ' list-upvoted ' if upload.upvoted? %>'
```

However, if this span is both downvoted & upvoted, it applies both styles.

How do I modify this to only apply one, and get rid of the other if the other does exist?

i.e. if this item has been downvoted before, remove the `list-downvoted` class, and vice versa.

Edit: Added the recommended code in my `UploadsHelper`

```
module UploadsHelper
    def best_span_class_for_upload(upload)
      # Start with the base style
      css_class = 'best_in_place'

      # Add on any conditional styles using String#<< concatenation
      css_class << ' list-downvoted' if (upload.downvoted?)
      css_class << ' list-upvoted' if (upload.upvoted?)

      # Return the result
      css_class
    end
end
```

With the span looking like this now:

```
<span class='<%= best_span_class_for_upload(upload) %>' id='best_in_place_upload_name' data-url='<%= upload_path(upload) %>' data-object='upload' data-attribute='name' data-formType='input' data-activator='span#upload-edit-name-<%= upload.id %>'><%= upload.name %></span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be better to roll up into a helper method to avoid making a mess of your template:

```
<span class='<%= best_span_class_for_upload(upload) %>'>
```

Then the helper method defined in a `helper/` defined module would look like this:

```
def best_span_class_for_upload(upload)
  # Start with the base style
  css_class = 'best_in_place'

  # Add on any conditional styles using String#<< concatenation
  css_class << ' list-downvoted' if (upload.downvoted?)
  css_class << ' list-upvoted' if (upload.upvoted?)

  # Return the result
  css_class
end
```

**Update:**

Revised version that shows only one of up or down:

```
def best_span_class_for_upload(upload)
  # Start with the base style
  css_class = 'best_in_place'

  # Add on any conditional styles using String#<< concatenation
  if (upload.downvoted?)
    css_class << ' list-downvoted' 
  elsif (upload.upvoted?)
    css_class << ' list-upvoted'
  end

  # Return the result
  css_class
end
```

Comment: would it be in an 'upload_helper' ?

Comment: Btw, that doesn't work. I updated the question with the code I used. Maybe I am missing something ?

Comment: When you say doesn't work, what do you mean? Errors? The helper method should construct a simple string based on the logic you defined. The view just exercises this same method. If you're putting this in a view used by UploadsController, then you should put it in the associated `app/helpers/uploads_helper.rb`.

Comment: Sorry, it applies both styles - regardless of what was done before....which was my original question. What I want it to do is if the current class is `list-downvoted` and `upload.upvoted?` is true, it should remove `list-downvoted` and add `list-upvoted`. How would I do that with the helper ?

Comment: You could change that `if`-`if` to an `if`-`elsif` instead and that should do what you want, basically add one or the other but not both.

Comment: Can you change it, so it is more clear ? I am not sure what you are talking about.

Comment: That update solves half of the problem, but what happens if an image has been voted on before, and the style `list-upvoted` has been applied to it. So the last thing is to remove that other class if it exists, then add the new class like you have.

Comment: You can just switch the order of the conditions around if you want one of them to come out on top. I'm not sure what you mean otherwise.